# Unable to access _layouts from custom login.aspx

Tags: sharepoint, forms-authentication

I have a custom login.aspx form for SharePoint FBA.  However, I want to reference files (images, css etc) in _layouts\me\css etc.  each time i try, i get redirected to the login page!

How can i get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was pretty easy.  Went into IIS, click on security, and add a rule to allow anonymous users.

Answer (score 0):

you can also make it with visual studio. open website.